# Each vertex of this tree is either red or blue. How many possible trees are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question: Let $X$ denote the set of 'coloured trees' which result when each vertex of the tree is assigned one of the colours red or blue. How many different coloured trees of this kind are there?

[image: This is a tree.]

I am not quite sure where to begin with this question. We are studying Burnside's Lemma and the orbit-stabilizer theorem, so I'm assuming these are necessary to solve the problem.

What really throws me off is that there are only 7 vertices, so if each one is red or blue, do I consider all these cases?

- 4 red, 3 blue
- 3 red, 4 blue
- 2 red, 5 blue
- 5 red, 2 blue
- 1 red, 6 blue
- 6 red, 1 blue
- 7 red, 0 blue
- 0 red, 7 blue

The previous problem asked to find the automorphism group $G$ on the set of vertices of this tree, which I obtained. So maybe there is a way to apply $G$ to the trees with red or blue vertices in order to solve these? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do adjacent vertices have to have different colors? If so, the number of colorings is $2$, because the color of the root (which may be any node) determines the color of all other nodes.

Comment: The question does not specify, so I believe that adjacent vertices can be the same color.

Comment: Or is the 'problem' that the two subtrees of any node are indistinguishable if they have the same color, and thus some colorings overlap?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. Everything stated in the question is written above.

Comment: It is not really clear when two colored trees are considered distinct.

Comment: They are considered distinct if they are in different orbits. The orbit is defined as an equivalence class of $G$ on $X$, where $G$ is some group of permutations. In this case I believe that $G$ is the group of symmetries on the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a tree with $1,2,4$ blue is the same as a tree with $1,2,5$ blue.  I would count as follows:

First consider the subtree of $2,4,5$.  Vertex $2$ has two choices and vertices $4,5$ have three choices, so there are six ways to color the subtree.  Now for the whole tree, you have two choices for $1$.  You have $6$ ways to choose the colorings of the two subtrees so they match and $\frac 12\cdot 6 \cdot 5=15$ ways to choose two different colorings of the subtrees, for a total of $2(6+15)=42$

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I am wondering if you know how to solve this with the orbit-stabilizer theorem or Burnside's lemma?

Comment: I think the counting is in the spirit of Burnside's lemma.  The elements of the group are the automorphisms $4 \leftrightarrow 5,6 \leftrightarrow 7,(4,6) \leftrightarrow (5,7)$, etc.  I haven't done the details, though

Comment: Yes you are right, I had to find the automorphism group in the last problem. Thanks :)